# How to render a view from a different controller in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I am having a problem trying to  call render on views from two seperate controllers and retrieve the html automatically to the original function. I tried $this->render, but this fails because the views contain GET parameters. Is there any way to render a view from a different controller when GET parameters are needed ?
thanks.

Comment: More detail on "this fails because.."  why does having GET parameters affect anything?

Comment: The view won't receive any GET paramenter, just vars. Only controllers receive GET parameters, if you `set()` the same vars expected by the view, you should be able to call a different controller view. Try elaborating more the situation or posting some code for us.

Comment: Plus, `render()` can't be called on views.

Comment: @rlcabral yes it can

Answer (score 2):

For people having the same question, you can do this in a controller:

```
$view = new View($this, false); // Create a new instance of the View class
$view->layout = 'ajax'; // Optional, use if you want a "clean" view
$view->set(compact('parameter1', 'parameter2')); // Send parameters to the view
$out = $view->render('url'); // Store the resultant HTML in the $out variable
```

Comment: does this work for rendering a View from a Different Controller?  How does CakePHP know which folder in your View folder to pull from?